# [ROS2] How to check for incoming param type?

Tags: ros, ros2, parameter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I receive a parameter update and want to check if its the correct type, how could I do this?
Because if I set a param over cmd line and write 1 instead of 1.0, no exception is thrown when receiving the param with false type.

```
void handleChangedParameters( const rcl_interfaces::msg::ParameterEvent::SharedPtr& event )
   {
      for ( auto& changed_parameter : event->changed_parameters )
      {
         auto paramName = changed_parameter.name;
         if ( paramName == controllerFrequency )
         {
            log_info(" is integer: {}", changed_parameter.value. == XXX  ? "true" : "false" )
            updateFrequencyParam( changed_parameter.value.integer_value );
         }
      }
   }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330547/%5Bros2%5D-how-to-check-for-incoming-param-type?/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2019-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, found the answer...

```
rclcpp::ParameterType::PARAMETER_BOOL
```

---

Originally posted by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) with karma: 496 on 2019-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1